# Use a CASE expression Column value in another CASE expression in SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select, case

I am trying to user one column obtained from the CASE expression to SET another Column Value.

E.G. I have a table user with multiple column. First, I need to set the status of a project based on the values of some columns in the table. I am able to make this part work. The second part is, based on the status value, I need to get the user name(s) from multiple columns. When I do that, am getting an error

> Invalid Column 'Status'

A sample query follows:

```
  SELECT
  STATUS = CASE WHEN ISNULL(USER1,'') = '1' THEN 'Approve'
           WHEN ISNULL(USER2,'') = '2' THEN 'Reject'
           WHEN ISNULL(USER3,'') = '3' THEN 'Pending Decision'
           ELSE 'error' END,
 USERNAME = CASE WHEN ISNULL(STATUS,'') = 'Approve' THEN (select username1 from <table> where userid = <userid>)
           WHEN ISNULL(STATUS,'') = 'Reject' THEN  (select username2 from <table> where userid = <userid>)
           WHEN ISNULL(STATUS,'') = 'Pending Decision' THEN  (select username3 from <table> where userid = <userid>)
           ELSE 'error' END

           from <table> where userid = <userid>
```

Comment: As the second set of case conditions exactly map to the output of the first why can't you just use the first lot again? Also you can remove all the ISNULL

Comment: Thank you.  I did not think that way!! Let me check that.

Comment: Reusing the same case statment worked for me!! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't reuse an expression defined in the `select` clause in the same clause.

I don't really see why you need the value returned by the first expression to compute the second value, since the logic is basically the same.

You can just do:

```
select
    case 
        when user1 = 1 then then 'Approve'
        when user2 = 2 then 'Reject'
        when user3 = 3 then 'Pending Decision'
        else 'error' 
    end status,
    case 
        when user1 = 1 then (select username1 from <table> where userid = <userid>)
        when user2 = 2 then (select username2 from <table> where userid = <userid>)
        when user3 = 3 then (select username3 from <table> where userid = <userid>)
    end username
from <table> where userid = <userid>
```

Notes

- `isnull()` is unnecessary, since the alternative value is not trapped anywhere in the `case` statement
- this treats `user1` as a number, because it looks like it - so I unquoted the test values in the `case` statement. If it's actually a string, you can revert this and add the single quotes.
- I am quite suspicious about the logic of the subqueries; there might be ways to simplify that, if you were to provide more details on what they are intented to do, along with sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1):

This works, because @status will be processed before username

And you have to use user defined variables, you can't use columnnames for that

```
  SELECT
  @status := (CASE WHEN COALESCE(USER1,'') = '1' THEN 'Approve'
           WHEN COALESCE(USER2,'') = '2' THEN 'Reject'
           WHEN COALESCE(USER3,'') = '3' THEN 'Pending Decision'
           ELSE 'error' END)  `STATUS` 
           ,
  CASE WHEN COALESCE(@status,'') = 'Approve' THEN (select username1 from table1 where userid = 20)
          WHEN COALESCE(@status,'') = 'Reject' THEN  (select username2 from table1 where userid = 20)
           WHEN COALESCE(@status,'') = 'Pending Decision' THEN  (select username3 from table1 where userid = 20)
           ELSE 'error' END USERNAME 

           from table1 where userid = 20
```

Comment: Thank you. Am getting an error "Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 10
Incorrect syntax near 'status'"

Comment: ISNULL only can omly have 1 parameter i used now COALESCE which takes teh forst non NULL value

Answer (score 1):

You can use a "table expression" to pre-compute a column. For example:

```
select
  *,
  -- use the pre-computed STATUS column now
from (
  SELECT *,
    <CASE-expression> as status
  from <table> where userid = <userid>
) x
```

Comment: ISNULL allows only 1 parameter in mysql

Comment: Despite the tag they are using SQL Server (from Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 10 Incorrect syntax near 'status'")